# Mongoose build query to update multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to create endpoint which will update multiple fields from one collection but not every field and I don't know exact amount of fields.

So for example my user.model contain fields like `email`, `password`, `name`, `active`. Now I want to create endpoint which will be allowed to change `name` and `password` but not `email` and `active`. Also it can change both values at once or just one depending on what is sent. So if I pass to it JSON like this:

```
{ "password":"someNewPass" }
```

it will update password but won't touch other fields and when I will send JSON like this:

```
{ "password":"someNewPass", "name":"John Smith" }
```

then it will update both values but when I send JSON like this

```
{ "password":"someNewPass", "name":"John Smith", "active":false }
```

it will not allow the action and give status forbidden or something.

I know I can update multiple fields like this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'resetPasswordKey': req.query.key },
  { $set: { 'password': newPasswordHash, 'name': 'John Smith' } }
)
```

but how to handle that I don't know amount of fields which will be sent (one or two in above example) and I don't want to let update every field (forbid `email` and `active` in above example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
let update = { "password":"someNewPass", "name":"John Smith", "active":false }
if(update.hasOwnProperty('active'))
{
    throw 'forbidden';
} 
else
{
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { 'resetPasswordKey': req.query.key },
      { $set: update }
    )
}
```

Comment: Yeah but in real project I have model with 40 fields and 25 of them will be allowed to update and 15 not. And this model may grow so this solution would be very messy

Comment: You can create a list of forbidden fields then check every field in the update object. If any of its fields is in this list you can then throw the exception.